# jQuery function wont work after CSS Class change

Tags: jquery, css

I actualy have some trouble with a function after a CSS class change.

Here is my Code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Animate Test</title>
    <style>
    .animatebox { width: 300px; margin: auto; height: 50px; background: grey; position: absolute; bottom: 250; padding-left: 10px;}
    .hiddenstuff { opacity: 0; } 
    .boxtitle { font-size: 18px; font-weight: 100;}
    .clear { clear: both;}
    .arrow_up { float: right; margin: 7px 0 0 125px; padding-right: 10px;}
    .arrow_down { float: right; margin: 7px 0 0 125px; padding-right: 10px;}
    p {margin: 15px 0 0 0;}
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Animate Test</h1>
<div id="content">
<div class="animatebox">
<img class="arrow_up" height="35px" src="arrow_up.png"><p class="boxtitle">Lala Box</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="hiddenstuff">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata </p>
</div>
</div>


<script>

$(function() {
$('.arrow_up').click(function(){
   $('.arrow_up').attr('src',"arrow_down.png");
});
$('.arrow_up').click(function () {
    $('.arrow_up').addClass('arrow_down');
});
$('.arrow_up').click(function () {
    $('.arrow_up').removeClass('arrow_up');
});
});

$(".arrow_up").click(function () {
    $('.animatebox').animate ({
        height: '250px'
    }, 200 );
});

$(".arrow_up").click(function () {
    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200 );
});

$(".arrow_up").click(function () {
    $('.boxtitle').animate ({
        fontSize: '28px',
        fontWeight: '700'
    }, 200 );
});

$(".arrow_down").click(function () {
    $('.animatebox').animate ({
        height: '50px'
    }, 200 );

});

$(".arrow_down").click(function () {
    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '0'
    }, 200 );
});


$(".arrow_down").click(function () {
    $('.boxtitle').animate ({
        fontSize: '18px',
        fontWeight: '100'
    }, 200 );
});




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

After clicking the up buttons once it changes the class to "arrow_down", but the function for the down animation wont work then?!? :/

**UPDATE**

```
$("body").on("click", ".arrow_up", function () {
        $('.arrow_up').attr('src',"arrow_down.png");
        $('.arrow_up').addClass('arrow_down');
        $('.arrow_up').removeClass('arrow_up');

        $('.animatebox').animate ({
            height: '250px'
        }, 200 );

        $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
            opacity: '1'
        }, 200 );

        $('.boxtitle').animate ({
            fontSize: '28px',
            fontWeight: '700'
        }, 200 );
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".arrow_down", function () {
        $('.arrow_down').attr('src',"arrow_up.png");
        $('.arrow_down').addClass('arrow_up');
        $('.arrow_down').removeClass('arrow_down');

        $('.animatebox').animate ({
            height: '50px'
        }, 200 );

        $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
            opacity: '0'
        }, 200 );

        $('.boxtitle').animate ({
            fontSize: '18px',
            fontWeight: '100'
        }, 200 );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's dynamic, use `on`. Also, you can shorten the code some:

```
$("body").on("click", ".arrow_up", function () {
    $('.arrow_up').attr('src',"arrow_down.png");
    $('.arrow_up').addClass('arrow_down');
    $('.arrow_up').removeClass('arrow_up');

    $('.animatebox').animate ({
        height: '250px'
    }, 200 );

    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200 );

    $('.boxtitle').animate ({
        fontSize: '28px',
        fontWeight: '700'
    }, 200 );
});

$("body").on("click", ".arrow_down", function () {
    $('.animatebox').animate ({
        height: '50px'
    }, 200 );

    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '0'
    }, 200 );

    $('.boxtitle').animate ({
        fontSize: '18px',
        fontWeight: '100'
    }, 200 );
});
```

You don't need an event handler for every single thing you're going to do. This will be just fine (and probably a bit better with performance)

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KjZXL/)

Answer (score 1):

`$('.arrow_up')` returns the list of all *currently present* elements with the class of `arrow_up`. Your `.arrow_down` elements are being dynamically created, so when you bind the events on page load, those elements aren't actually there.

You'll need to bind the events slightly differently in order to account for dynamically-created elements:

```
$('body').on('click', '.arrow_down', function() {
  ...

$('body').on('click', '.arrow_up', function() {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As Blender stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615474/1516616)

> **$('.arrow_up')** returns the list of all currently present elements with the class of arrow_up. Your .arrow_down elements are being dynamically created, so when you bind the events on page load, those elements aren't actually there.
>
> You'll need to bind the events slightly differently in order to account for dynamically-created elements:

So try the following code:

```
// Arrow Up Click Event
$('body').on('click', '.arrow_up', function(){

   $('.arrow_up').attr('src',"arrow_down.png");
   $('.arrow_up').removeClass('arrow_up').addClass('arrow_down');

   $('.animatebox').animate ({
        height: '250px'
   }, 200 );

   $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '1'
   }, 200 );

   $('.boxtitle').animate ({
        fontSize: '28px',
        fontWeight: '700'
   }, 200 );
});

// Arrow Down Click Event
$('body').on('click', '.arrow_down', function(){ 

   $('.arrow_down').attr('src',"arrow_up.png");
   $('.arrow_down').removeClass('arrow_down').addClass('arrow_up');

   $('.animatebox').animate ({
       height: '50px'
   }, 200 );

   $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '0'
   }, 200 );

   $('.boxtitle').animate ({
        fontSize: '18px',
        fontWeight: '100'
    }, 200 );
});
```

[**SEE A SMALL DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktQwQ/)

​

Answer (score 0):

You should bind all the event in the `ready` event, that way you can put the script in the `head`.

Don't bind on event for each thing that you want to do, you can do more than one thing in an event handler. Also, you can chain jQuery methods so that you don't have to select the same element over and over.

When you bind events, they are only bound on the elements that exist at that time, so the events for `.arrow_up` won't be bound as there are no such elements when the code runs. To handle events for elements that changes, you need to use a delegate instead of binding the event on the element. You bind the delegate on an element that doesn't change, like the `.animatebox` element.

```
$(function() {

  $('.animatebox').on('click', '.arrow_up', function(){
    $('.arrow_up').attr('src',"arrow_down.png").addClass('arrow_down').removeClass('arrow_up');
    $('.animatebox').animate ({
      height: '250px'
    }, 200 );
    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
      opacity: '1'
    }, 200 );
    $('.boxtitle').animate ({
      fontSize: '28px',
      fontWeight: '700'
    }, 200 );
  });

  $('.animatebox').on('click', '.arrow_down', function () {
    $('.animatebox').animate ({
      height: '50px'
    }, 200 );
    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
      opacity: '0'
    }, 200 );
    $('.boxtitle').animate ({
      fontSize: '18px',
      fontWeight: '100'
    }, 200 );
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use events on a element that has ever changing class.. Why don't you use a **ID**  instead.. Also there is no need to write up each event seperately.. They can be handled in a single event and with lot less confusion..

I have given the id **arrowImg**  to the Img element..

```
  $(function() {
    $('#arrowImg').on('click', function() {
        var height = '250px';
        var opacity = '1';
        var fontSize = '28px';
        var fontWeight =  '700';
        if ($(this).hasClass('arrow_up')) {
            $(this).attr('src', "arrow_down.png").toggleClass()('arrow_down').removeClass('arrow_up');
        }
        else {
            height = '50px';
            opacity = '0';
            fontSize = '18px';
            fontWeight ='100';
            $(this).attr('src', "arrow_up.png").addClass('arrow_up').removeClass('arrow_down');
        }

        $('.animatebox').animate({
            height: height
        }, 200);
        $('.hiddenstuff').animate({
            opacity: opacity
        }, 200);
        $('.boxtitle').animate({
            fontSize: fontSize,
            fontWeight: fontWeight
        }, 200);
    });
});​
```

The code can be more optimized by removing the repetitive lines...

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5SCnf/3/)

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5SCnf/4/)

Comment: Sorry about that, started a few days ago with jquery :/